# Mounting an NFS share with udp or mntudp options

Tags: macos, tcpip, nfs, udp

According to the documentation of `NFS` client on `Mac OS X 10.7` user can specify following options:

```
udp     Use UDP transport protocol.
```

and

```
mntudp  Force the mount protocol to use UDP transport, even for TCP NFS
        mounts.  (Necessary for some old BSD servers.)
```

What is the difference between these two options?